# Definition of totally geodesic flat submanifold

Tags: definition, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I don't know if this is an inappropriate question to post on stackexchange, but could somebody give me (reference me) a precise definition of "totally geodesic and flat submanifold" of a riemannian manifold?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold. A submanifold $N$ of $M$ is **totally geodesic** if every geodesic in $N$ is also a geodesic in $M$. $N$ is **flat** if its curvature vanishes.

Let me know if there is anything above that you would like further clarification on.